# How to concatenate this code? I have tried doing it and I have no luck

Tags: javascript, concatenation

```
    $(".featured").append("<div>" + 
      "{% for product in collections['no-show-socks-for-" + genderText + "'].products %}" + 
      "<img src=" + "{{product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large'}}" + ">" + 
      "{% endfor %}" + "</div>")
```

[image: **Trying to concatenate the code inside the append function and for some reason my code doesn't work?**]

I have an app that lets the user click  between male or female. Based on what the user clicks, some form of information should pop up. The information that I want is inside the append function but for some reason its not showing up? I think it might be because it's not concatenated properly?

Comment: add code using `{}` or `<>` buttons, not in images

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try using back-ticks and check it in Babel Try it out.

$(".featured").append(`<div>
{% for product in collections['no-show-socks-for-${genderText}'].products %}
<img src="{{product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large'}}">
{% endfor %}
</div>`)

https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=CQCgRAdAZgpghgFwK4CcYBMwEoJwA54wB26IABgDzoCWAbgHwBQAkAN4CkABFAPYqd4UPdEgDGCTtSKdRPADZyY46jyIBnANoByIjwC0agBY8A7gZ6iA1mr28Ue4KwDmxdDBQAVGAA8EAXy0AXQhBYTEENU52PxZmCmoAWydONRRRAF4wVlZQkXFoeGQ0dAB9RLgXTgAfASE8hDKkktQ5AC5OLTk4FBctPz8wJjYuVzsomLiAehoGMiwgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the back-ticks for concatenate multiple line of code on js

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings